dashboard_activity hook
Is there a way to hook the dashboard_activity by adding the recently published Custom Posts? without any plugin.
And how to do so?
Some help would be appreciated.
Thx.

Using the dashboard_recent_posts_query_args filter, you can add your custom post types to the query args, and they'll be included (untested):
add_filter( 'dashboard_recent_posts_query_args', static function ( $args ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $args['post_type'] ) ) {
        $args['post_type'] = array( $args['post_type'] );
    }

    $args['post_type'][] = 'cpt';

    return $args;
} );


It works perfectly! Thx so much. Is there any way to add more than the date and title in this widget?

There is not a means of changing the widget to include more data. May want to consider a custom dashboard widget.

@madeleod if this answer satisfies your question, you should consider marking it as accepted to remove it from the "Unanswered" feeds and to reward Caleb for their efforts, among other things :)
